# Debug button blacked out in Visual Studio 2019 in new project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

So I'm just starting to learn C# with the W3 school tutorial. I followed the instructions but I bumped into a wall when it came to debugging the automatically generated code example. The button is just blacked out and not working even if I press F5. I've made sure the right code or file is selected.

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMyql.png

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What type of project is it, and what is the startup project of the solution set to?

Comment: @dxiv So the IDE is setup with the .NET Framework and the unity developement pack. The project is a console application. I'm not sure if thats what you are looking for but as I said I'm very new to this and have absolutely no clue whats going on. Feel free to ask for more specifications

Comment: Does it work if you follow the [Tutorial: Create a simple C# console app in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2019), or if not at what step does it diverge from what's shown there?

Comment: @dxiv I found a solution as you can see in the answer I wrote

Comment: You may not have all necessary Core workloads installed in VS. Anyway, the Framework may be friendlier for tutorials targeted at the Windows desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem I had to create the project as a Console app (.NET Framework). I created my project as Console application first one on this image. When I chose the second one the debugging worked fine

[image]